# Prevent folder upload in jQuery File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am using blueimp jQuery-File-Upload  for uploading files (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) . I wish to prevent users to drag folders to the drop area in Google Chrome (or any other brwosers). I have tried the option multiple and multiple directory webkitdirectory mozdirectory . I do not want user to drop folder in any browser(including chrome).

Does we have the option to prevent folder? Or can we have the option to zip a folder before it appears drop area?  Or Is it possible to show an alert message that indicate, the user have to convert the folder to zip/rar and drag?

Comment: It should be noted that one reason to **not support** dropping folders in your web app is that Google Chrome 55 does not correct set the `file.type` (aka ContentType) for some files types (zip, doc, xls) inside folders. It will set the `file.type` to an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I had this same issue.  The way to detect it on Chrome is to look for `data.originalFiles.length > 1`, and on Firefox you want to look for `data.files[0].size === 0`.

I tried playing around with setting the options for `minFileSize: 1`, `maxNumberOfFiles: 1` (and setting `getNumberOfFiles` too!), `singleFileUploads: false`, and `limitMultiFileUploads: 1`... but none of them seemed to work very well, and the documentation was kind of fuzzy and the code a bit convoluted.

They do have an option for validations (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#processqueue), but the example uses the deprecated `$.Deferred` method in jQuery.

So, I ended up doing something like this (I removed all of my custom stuff and extras to make it a little more simple/to the point):

```
var jqXHR = null;

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  multipart: false,
  add: function(e, data) {
    if (data.originalFiles.length > 1 || data.files[0].size === 0) {
      fileError(null, 'zip');
    } else {
      jqXHR = data.submit();
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    self.fileError(jqXHR, textStatus);
  }
});

var fileError = function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  var statusCode = jqXHR ? jqXHR.status : 0;
  // Figure out something nice to say, then close modal and clear out input box.
  var friendlyError = 'Your file failed to upload.';

  if (textStatus === 'abort') {
    friendlyError = 'Your file upload was aborted.';
  } else if (textStatus === 'error') {
    friendlyError = 'There was a server error that prevented your file from being uploaded.';
  } else if (textStatus === 'zip') {
    friendlyError = 'This file cannot be uploaded. Please zip the file and try again.';
  }

  // Your custom UI code here!
};
```

Basically, if it's got more than one file or the file size is 0, trigger the error code instead of submitting the `jqXHR` data. Then, override the error handling in `fileupload` to *also* use this error handler, because DRY.

Comment: the code 'data.originalFiles.length" haven't  worked for me.
When I used the lines  
myJsonVin =JSON.stringify(data);
  var json_obj_vin = JSON.parse(myJsonVin);
lenVin = json_obj_vin["files"].length;

It showed the number of files in a dragged folder.
This worked in Chrome, but not in firefox (on Windows).

Comment: <code>
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/php/'
}).on('fileuploaddrop', function (e, data) {
  
 myJsonVin =JSON.stringify(data);
 var json_obj_vin = JSON.parse(myJsonVin);
 lenVin = json_obj_vin["files"].length;  
 if(lenVin>1){
  alert("Please Zip your folder before you up!");
  return false;
 }

}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
$('#divupload').load('listfiles.php');
}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    alert("File upload successfully")
});
</code>

Comment: Yeah, that's what I explained above. FF and Chrome handle it differently for whatever reason. :) You're only setting `lenVin` to `json_obj_vin["files"].length` and then testing if it's `>1`. You should try this instead: `if (json_obj_vin["files"].length > 1 || json_obj_vin.files[0].size === 0) { alert("Please zip your folder blah blah"); ... }` and remove the `linVin = ..."` line. Also, it's good practice to properly scope your variables by putting `var` in front of them. ;)

Comment: Hey @Vinod -- I think this is correct and that you missed a small detail, you should consider marking it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't find option but it changed code in jquery.fileupload.js

```html
 } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
       // directory drag prevent
       //dirReader = entry.createReader();
       //readEntries();
} else {
```